# How can I get next value from a python dictionary after matching the key value with some string

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to get the value (`fcs`) when the key value is `"Team"`. I tried with python code but was not able to get the value once the key is matched with "Team".

`[{'key':'appid','value':'xyz'},{'key':'Team','value':'fcs'},{'key':'incident','value':'a1435621'}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, using `next()`:

```py
lst = [
    {"key": "appid", "value": "xyz"},
    {"key": "Team", "value": "fcs"},
    {"key": "incident", "value": "a1435621"},
]

team = next(d["value"] for d in lst if d["key"] == "Team")
print(team)
```

Prints:

```
fcs
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries have the structure

```
dict = {
key1: value1,
key2: value2,
}
```

I would recommend changing your data structure into the form above rather than have an list of dictionaries. That way, your data will look like this

```
data = {
appleid:"xyz",
Team:"fcs",
incident:"a1435621"
}
```

That way, you can call your data like this

```
print(data.Team) #this will output "fcs"
```

If you still want to keep your original structure of data, you write a for loop that goes through each dictionary and once you find the one that matches, you can store the index and call it

```
index = 0
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if data[i].key == "Team":
        index = i
print(data[i].value)
```